# I have 5 cards that have the 'data-price' attribute assigned, I need to output all the values of these attributes via js

Tags: javascript

I have 5 cards that have the 'data-price' attribute assigned,. I need to output all the values of these attributes via js,. my code outputs only the first value of the card.

Why doesn't it work?

Here is my code
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<button class="sort">Сортируй!</button>
<div class="card">
        <!-- 1 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="6000">
                    6000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 2 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="5000">
                    5000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 3 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="4000">
                    4000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 4 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="3000">
                    3000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 5 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="2000">
                    2000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.card {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.first_card {
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 20px;
}
.field {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

```
const number = document.querySelector("#tentacles");
const btn = document.querySelector('.sort')
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.first_card')
const price = document.querySelector('.price').getAttribute('data-prise');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => { 
    for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        console.log(price)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use querySelectorAll to get the prices and then iterate on them

```
const number = document.querySelector("#tentacles");
const btn = document.querySelector('.sort')
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.first_card')
const prices = document.querySelectorAll('.price')
btn.addEventListener('click', () => { 
    for(let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        console.log(price[i].getAttribute('data-prise'))
    }
})
```

Comment: i get an error - 'getAttribute is not a function'

Comment: Here's the documentation for [QSA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). QSA returns a _list_ of nodes which you have to iterate over, and for each node in that list you can use `getAttribute`. @al.orl

Comment: @al.orl i updated my code with the complete version

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll()` to get all the price elements, then loop through them and get the `data-prise` attribute value for each:

```js
const number = document.querySelector("#tentacles");
const btn = document.querySelector('.sort')
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.first_card')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => { 
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.price')).forEach(el => {
    console.log(el.getAttribute('data-prise'));
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.first_card {
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 20px;
}
.field {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<button class="sort">Сортируй!</button>
<div class="card">
        <!-- 1 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="6000">
                    6000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 2 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="5000">
                    5000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 3 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="4000">
                    4000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 4 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="3000">
                    3000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 5 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="2000">
                    2000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closer , just use querySelectorAll and get data-prise attribute inside the loop.

```
const priceList = document.querySelectorAll('.price')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => { 
   for (const element of priceList) {
       console.log(element.getAttribute('data-prise'));
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) you can specifically target those elements with a data attribute. Either use `forEach` or [another loop variant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) to get the data, or coerce ([`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)/[spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) the array-like node list that `querySelectorAll` returns to a proper array, and use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return an array of prices.

Note: you may find it convenient to turn the string values from those attributes into integers if you have to do any math operations on them at a later date.

```js
// Get the node list of elements that have a data-prise
// attribute, and coerce it to an array
const els = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-prise]')];

// Create an array of numbers by `mapping` over that element
// array, and for each element return the data attribute value
// In this case the string value is coerced to an integer
const prices = els.map(el => Number(el.dataset.prise));

console.log(prices);
```

```html
<button class="sort">Сортируй!</button>
<div class="card">
  <!-- 1 card -->
  <div class="first_card">
    <div class="img_card">
      <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
    </div>
    <div class="text_card">
      <div class="desc">
        Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
      </div>
      <div class="price" data-prise="6000">
        6000
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- 2 card -->
  <div class="first_card">
    <div class="img_card">
      <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
    </div>
    <div class="text_card">
      <div class="desc">
        Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
      </div>
      <div class="price" data-prise="5000">
        5000
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- 3 card -->
  <div class="first_card">
    <div class="img_card">
      <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
    </div>
    <div class="text_card">
      <div class="desc">
        Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
      </div>
      <div class="price" data-prise="4000">
        4000
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- 4 card -->
  <div class="first_card">
    <div class="img_card">
      <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
    </div>
    <div class="text_card">
      <div class="desc">
        Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
      </div>
      <div class="price" data-prise="3000">
        3000
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- 5 card -->
  <div class="first_card">
    <div class="img_card">
      <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
    </div>
    <div class="text_card">
      <div class="desc">
        Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
      </div>
      <div class="price" data-prise="2000">
        2000
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```